# bcrypt or MD5 (prestashop + Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, prestashop-1.7

One question! I'm working on a little project that involves prestashop 1.7 and Node.JS .
The question is, can I use the bcrypt-nodejs to generate and verify prestashops passwords?

https://www.npmjs.co...e/bcrypt-nodejs

Like:
const COOKIEKEY = env.config.COOKIEKEY;

var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("COOKIEKEY");

Thank you! best regards!

Answer (score 0):

When saving a password verifier just using a hash function such as MD5 is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as PBKDF2, Rfc2898DeriveBytes, password_hash, **bcrypt**, passlib.hash or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score -1):

I'm wondering the same thing...
did you found any solution?

Thanks

EDIT: 
i found a solution using this https://github.com/emn178/js-md5

```
md5(PRESTASHOP_COOKIE_KEY + password);
```

Comment: Hi Jack. Please use the answer function exclusively for answering questions, not for asking things like "I'm wondering the same thing... did you found any solution?" as this does by no means answer the question.

Comment: Do not use MD5 for a password verifier, that is not secure and puts the users at risk.

Comment: My problem was not exactly the same. i need to compare password hashed with key by prestashop and the password typed by the user on a form.

Comment: When the password is first entered a password verifier is generated and saved. When verifying a password (ex: for login) run the password through the same verifier and compare the result with the saved verifier.

Comment: password verifier? I'm not sure to understand. As far i know, Prestashop only save hashed password. So i compare password hashed and saved by prestashop with the password typed and sent by the form. You mean prestashop save a password verifier as well?

Comment: The hashed password is a password verifier, that is it is used to verify that the entered password is correct.

Comment: Then i don't understand what is wrong by doing comparaison with a string hashed the same way that prestashop did.